# Regex accepting spaces before and after string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to do a regex which accepts a string containing 3-10 characters (white spaces before and after the string are allowed).

Why does this:

```
return (this.state.user.name.match(`^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{3,10})\s*$`));
```

returns false when I try to put white space(s) before and/or after the string?
(it works correctly if I don't put white spaces.)

I am probably missing something, because it works using the regex tester:
https://regex101.com/r/2371SM/1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable has spaces and is not trimmed?

Comment: I allow spaces to trim it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass the regex as a string you have to do double `\\` so that you are escaping the `\` and not the letter that follows it:

```js
console.log(((" abcd").match(`^\\s*([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{3,10})\\s*$`)));

console.log(((" abcd").match(/^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{3,10})\s*$/)));
```

Comment: You made my day. Thank you.